# Share iPhone data connection with WiFi router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, iphone

I have this very weird idea in mind. I am going to go on a trip with a few friends. One of them has an iPhone with unlimited international 4g, and I have a router, connected to a 12v 12.4AH VRLA battery.

**What I was thinking:**

We all connect to the router, and the router connects to the Web/Internet/Whatever using the iPhone's data plan.

Is this even possible? It'd be awesome if it is!

Comment: The router would have to have multiple radios.  The firmware would have to support extending an existing access point.  You provided no details on the router.

Comment: @Ramhound the router is a relatively old Linksys WRT54G

Comment: It will not be possible with the hardware you have.

Comment: Note to close voters: Just because the source of the Internet connection is a phone doesn't mean that connecting a router to that other wireless signal is off-topic. I'm voting Leave Open.

Comment: Why dont you use the hotspot feature on the phone to connect the devices you have up to 5 connections that can be used and more if its jailbroken.

Comment: I need some features only routers have. I am also hosting a Samba server using a Raspberry PI (connected via an ethernet cable to the router)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to take a laptop and tether the iPhone to the laptop to give the laptop Internet access.  Then use [Internet Connection Sharing](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/using-internet-connection-sharing) to share the Internet to your other devices.

Comment: I was thinking about that too, the only problem is: I can't bring my laptop with me. I'll accept this as the answer as this is the closest I can get to what I want